# How to change the CachingConnectionFactory timeout setting

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a use case where when the connectivity to rabbitmq goes down I need to manage the messages in different way.

I have a logic

```
RabbitTempate template // get template using API call
template.setReplyTimeout(10000);    
template.convertAndSend(message);
```

But the problem is when the rabbitmq server connectivity goes down Spring AMQP automatically waits for connectivity to get resolved for 5 min

But because of that the client thread calling that particular logic waits for 5 min .

Is there any way i can change it , I am using CachingConnectionFactory

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg value="rabbit-server-fqdn" />
        <property name="virtualHost" value="vhost" />
        <property name="username" value="username" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
        <property name="cacheMode" value="CONNECTION" />
        <property name="channelCacheSize" value="25" />
    </bean>
```

Is there any way I can override these settings from 5 min so that client API does not need to wait for such huge amount of time ?

Comment: There is no such "5 minute timeout"; the connection will be established on demand. There must be something else going on, perhaps something is wrong with your network.

Comment: So after how much time template.convertAndSend(message); throws an exception as I am using my own local RabbitMQ server where i have stopped the server as per my wish ,,, The Consumer threads immediately throws an exception but template.convertAndSend(message); takes around ~ 5 min so throw an exception which renders that particular thread unusable for ~ 5 min duration

Comment: There is nothing in the template and/or framework that will introduce that 5 minute delay; you should immediately get an exception on the `template.convertAndSend()`; something else must be going on; perhaps take a thread dump to figure out what's happening.